# Why is Fisher's information the *negative* of expected second derivative?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information),

> A "blunt" support curve (one with a shallow maximum) would have a low
>   negative expected second derivative

In my mind, a blunt support curve has slow-changing slope, hence small second derivative, hence big *negative* expected second derivative (instead of small).

Where am I wrong in my thinking?

Comment: Expected second derivative is an average. If you average small things, they are still small. Why do you think they become big?

Comment: It's because of the negative sign, not because of the expectation.

Comment: Well the second derivative is negative around the maximum, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test, why do you fixate on its size?

Comment: Ah! That's what I missed. I knew it would be something straightforward like that. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.